# Eliminate radicals from a symbolic expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I get a lot of expressions of the type

```
-(((11 + z) (13 - z + Sqrt[25 - 26 z + z^2]))/(
6 (-11 - z + Sqrt[25 - 26 z + z^2]) (7 - z + Sqrt[25 - 26 z + z^2])))
```

Which contain radicals in `z` but are in fact rational functions of `z` (a-priori). In this case

```
(11 + z)/(24 + 12 z)
```

Sometimes `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` can find the rational expression, but in more complicated cases they can not. Is there an elegant way to eliminate radicals from an arbitrary expression of this type? I could try to cook up an ansatz for the rational function based on power counting in `z` or something like that, but maybe there is a ready solution?

Comment: Do you have an example where `FullSimplify` fails to eliminate radicals?

Comment: It is a good case for `Cancel` (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cancel.html)

Comment: @yarchik Cancel does not seem to work even on the example from OP

Comment: @flinty I failed to produce one. I thought I have it but maybe it was just `Simplify` which didn't work. Anyway I deal with very large expressions so the full power of `FullSimplify` may be too much here. Also it seems I've found a workaround for my particular type of expressions so the question is no longer pressing for me although it could be nice to know the answer.